# WPF Register dependency property of interface (not class)

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, dependency-properties

I have an interface

```
public interface IEventForwardable
{
    void ForwardEvent(object sender, EventArgs args, object owner, params object[] optionalParameters);
}
```

a custom class which implements the interface `IEventForwardable`

```
public class ItemView : UserControl, IEventForwardable
{
    ...
    public virtual void ForwardEvent(object sender, EventArgs args, object owner, params object[] optionalParameters)
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

a custom control which inherits `ItemView`, therefore implements `IEventForwardable` and has overridden method `ForwardEvent`

```
public partial class MPIIItemView : ItemView
{
    ...
    public override void ForwardEvent(object sender, EventArgs args, object owner, params object[] optionalParameters)
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

a custom control with dependency property

```
public partial class DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent : UserControl
{
    protected static void OnEventForwardableControlPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent control = dependencyObject as DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent;
        control.EventForwardableControl = eventArgs.NewValue as IEventForwardable;
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventForwardableControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EventForwardableControl", typeof(IEventForwardable), typeof(DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent), new PropertyMetadata(OnEventForwardableControlPropertyChangedCallback));
    public IEventForwardable EventForwardableControl;
    public DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and custom control where `EventForwardableControl` is an object of type `MPIIItemView`

```
public partial class DynamicLuminaireScenariosGrid : UserControl
{
    public IEventForwardable EventForwardableControl;
    public DynamicLuminaireScenariosGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void InitializeCell()
    {
        ...
        FrameworkElementFactory cellFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent));
        cellFactory.SetValue(DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent.EventForwardableControlProperty, EventForwardableControl);
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to build `FrameworkElementFactory` of type `DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent` and pass a reference to `EventForwardableControl` by setting the property in `cellFactory` object.
Trying this, I get error

```
Additional information: 'AppcMP.Devices.Central.MPIIItemView' is not a valid value for 'FrameworkElementFactory.SetValue'; values derived from Visual or ContentElement are not supported.
```

Is there any possibility to register a custom dependency property of interface type? Am I missing some cast?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but the declaration of the `EventForwardableControl` dependency property is incomplete. It misses a CLR property wrapper with `GetValue` and `SetValue` calls.

Comment: I suspect this is simply not how `FrameworkElementFactory` is meant to be used (or was - [it's deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx#Anchor_5)). I assume you want this factory to create `DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent`s that all reference the same `IEventForwardable` instance?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I didn't know that this way is deprecated. Thanks. And yes, I want to create `DynamicLuminaireScenarioCellContent` s with the same `IEventForwardable` instance.